# nodejs : use jsftp on specific network interface

Tags: node.js, ftp

I am using [jsftp](https://github.com/sergi/jsftp).

Everything works fine when I connect to a regular FTP server on internet.
I want to connect to a serv on a local network, using another network interface but I can't find a way with jsftp, I didn't find any other ftp package that offer me something like this.

Is there anyway I can use another network interface ?

I make something like this:

```
var Ftp = new JSFtp({
    host: "10.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    port: port,
    user: username,
    pass: password
});
Ftp.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
Ftp.put(buff, filePath, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

I get this error :

```
{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect"}
```

But I can connect in shell using curl with something like :

```
curl --interface anotherinterface ftp://10.xxx.xxx.xxx
```